# bash: iterating through txt file lines can't read last line

Tags: bash, bash4

`while read p; do`
  `echo $p`
  `done < file.txt`

this code can read all lines in the file.txt except the last line any ideas why. 
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if youre in doubt about the last `\n` in the file, you can try:

```
while read p; do
echo $p
done < <(grep '' file.txt)
```

grep is not picky about the line endings ;)

you can use `grep . file.txt` for skipping empty lines...

Answer (score 7):

Well last line does not contain the newline character, as the other answers have pointed out. But the read command actually sets the `p` variable, and then instead of returning a success, returns an end of file error. So this error stops the loop from getting executed. You can still use the `p` variable which contains the last line from the file

```
while read -r p || [[ -n "$p" ]]
do
echo $p
done < file.txt
```

This puts 2 conditions to be tested, as with or, only if the first fails, the second gets executed. So, when the last line will cause an end of file error in `read`, we will check if the `p` is set or not. If yes, we will use that.

Answer (score 3):

cat file.txt and see if the very last line has a new line at the end of the last line or not.
If it does not then `while read p ; do echo $p done < file.txt` won't echo the last line put a new-line at the end of the last line in the text file