# shell script does not read last line from sysin

Tags: bash, shell, stdin, sysin

I try to get some data from sysin and here is my problem: if data are directed from a file, then the last line is not read.
Example of text file:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
done
```

And output:

```
$ ./test.sh < data.txt
line1
line2
```

If I write down at the end of my file null string output correct. But I don`t like it.
 How to fix this?

Comment: There are **lots** of duplicates for this one. Are you sure you tried to search for an existing answered question? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485555/read-last-line-of-file-in-bash-script-when-reading-file-line-by-line, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165135/how-to-use-while-read-bash-to-read-the-last-line-in-a-file-if-there-s-no-new, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627578/bash-iterating-through-txt-file-lines-cant-read-last-line

Comment: sorry for my inadvertence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need desperately to read files without EOL in the end, then you may check whether returned string is empty or not instead of checking `read` exit status:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  line=''
  read line
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Works, but quite considerably more verbose than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom for this is:

```
while read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
  : process "$line"
done
```

Thus, we proceed in the loop while **either**:

- We read a valid line of text (which requires a newline)
- We had a partial read (which results in a nonzero exit status, but leaves the variable non-empty).

Answer (score 0):

I bet you that data.txt is missing a trailing newline, try checking with

```
od -xa data.txt
```

Look at the end:

```
$ od -xa data.txt
0000000    696c    656e    0a31    696c    656e    0a32    696c    656e
          l   i   n   e   1  nl   l   i   n   e   2  nl   l   i   n   e
0000020    0033
          3
0000021
```

If you see the above you are missing the newline.

```
$ od -xa data-with-nl.txt
0000000    696c    656e    0a31    696c    656e    0a32    696c    656e
          l   i   n   e   1  nl   l   i   n   e   2  nl   l   i   n   e
0000020    0a33
          3  nl
0000022
```

Some shells will also show a `%` sign if trailing newline is missing, try:

```
$ cat data.txt
line1
line2
line3%
$
```

Comment: Exactly! But how to change my codethis situation? How to finish read file on EOF?

Comment: @Nawy What? You want to add the newline to `data.txt`?

Comment: no, I don`t. I just want to process file without newline at the end of file