# why a readline call in bash/ksh is only reading the first line

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

I have this piece of code:

```
file="/dir/conf/file.config"
# while loop
while IFS='|' read -r source target filecount
do
     echo "source: ${source}"
     echo "target: ${target}"
     echo "filecount: ${filecount}"
     echo "======================="
done < "$file"
```

the job of this code is to read this config file:

```
Source1|Target1|1
Source2|Target2|2
Source3|Target3|4
Source4|Target4|3
Source5|Target5|6
```

The read stops at Source4 and skips the last line.
How do I make sure it reads ALL the lines?
Thanks!

Comment: Add output of `cat -A /dir/conf/file.config` to your question.

Comment: This might help: [Shell script read missing last line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12916352/3776858) or [bash: iterating through txt file lines can't read last line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16627578/3776858)

Comment: that worked. Thanks!